# thread synchronization using message queues is not in order

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, message-queue, python-multithreading

The following code is from [Raymond's Pycon keynotes on cuncurrency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk), great presentation. It's a little long, so I'll start with the question:

- If **messages** are added together to a **queue**, and both should be printed before a thread is considered done, how come the they are printed scrumbled? Adding a 100ms delay between thread initialization solves this, and the output is as expected.

-

```
import Queue, time

counter_queue = Queue.Queue()
counter = 0

def counter_manager():
    # I have EXCLUSIVE rights to update the counter variable
    global counter

    while True:
        increment = counter_queue.get()
        counter += 1
        print_queue.put(['The count is {}\n'.format(counter),
                         '----------\n'])
        counter_queue.task_done()

t = threading.Thread(target=counter_manager)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
del t


print_queue = Queue.Queue()

def print_manager():
    # I have EXCLUSIVE rights to call the print keyword
    while True:
        job = print_queue.get()
        for line in job:
            print line
        print_queue.task_done()

t = threading.Thread(target=print_manager)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
del t

def worker_threads():
    counter_queue.put(1)

print_queue.put(['Starting up.. with message queues'])
worker_threads = []
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    worker_threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    # time.sleep(0.1)
for t in worker_threads:
    t.join()

counter_queue.join()
print_queue.put(['Finishing up'])
print_queue.join()
```

It uses `counter_manager` and `print_queue` as daemons to receive messages from the worker threads, and execute them sequentially. As I understand, this should preserve the order of execution. However, I get the following output:

```
Starting up.. with message queues
The couns is 1The couns is 2

--------------------

The couns is 3
 ----------The couns is 4
 The couns is 5
The couns is 6
----------
----------
----------
The couns is 7

----------The couns is 8

The couns is 9----------

----------The couns is 10

----------
Finishing up
```

The counter is incremented correctly, still the print messages are scrumbled.

If I uncomment the sleep statement, threads initialization is delayed by 100ms and the **output is correct**

```
Starting up.. with message queues
 The couns is 1
----------
The couns is 2
----------
The couns is 3
----------
The couns is 4
----------
The couns is 5
----------
The couns is 6
----------
The couns is 7
----------
The couns is 8
----------
The couns is 9
----------
The couns is 10
----------
Finishing up
```

Using the queues, prints should be in order. Isn't that correct?

---

The worker code

```
def worker():
    global counter

    counter += 1
    print 'The couns is {}'.format(counter)  # read the var (race cond.)
    print '----------'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to duplicate the issue. To get it to run, I added a `threading` import and renamed the `worker_threads` function to `worker`.

The output has "couns" but your code indicates "count". Can you verify that the output and code you are providing coincide?

Your output seems to only interleave at the line level.

I wonder if a previous version of the code had two different `.put`s (not atomic) in `counter_manager` that were later combined into a single `.put` with multiple lines?

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've defined a worker function the file on a different part and were using it. I mistakenly put `worker` instead of `worker_threads`

Comment: @Vinny Can you include the definition of `worker` then? `worker_threads` won't work as the `Thread` `target` because `worker_threads` is also defined as a list.

Comment: I added it. The worker method doesn't isn't atmoic. It is used to create a race condition, and solve it using message queues

Comment: And it's worker_queue on my original code. it's defined as `counter_queue.put(1)`, and this is the target of `Threading.thread`